# How to handle gaps in local cache

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile, synchronization

I have an application that aims to behave like the instagram app. This means:

When the user opens the app, latest content from the local database is displayed, but a request is fired to get the server's latest content. If the server returns such data, the local database gets populated with it and then the UI displays it.

So, how can I handle the gap that this can create between the records that already existed, and the newer ones? Let's say I get 10 items per page from my API, and there are 15 new ones. When the request returns, the latest 10 items get inserted in my local database this leaving a gap of 5 items with the ones that were already there. This could even happen several times if the user doesn't use the app a lot, and the gap could just be huge if they haven't used it in a while, so just firing a lot of request doesn't seem to be the solution.

And the second thing is stale data. Items that have been updated or deleted on the server. I can provide an endpoint to retrieve changes, and soft-delete records so they can still be get but with a "deleted" flag. But the question is: when and how should I request that? It doesn't simply belong in to the "Enter the app -> request latest items" flow. Should I just poll regularly, use some sort of notifications maybe? Then what if the user is offline?

I'm puzzled and I've been googling A LOT lately, and I haven't found a convincing solution. They all are SyncAdapter style stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure specific on instagram, but on the app I work on and what I see around other apps, is to delete the feed of local data when you `GET` the page 0. Then as the user scrolls down, it reloads from internet the next pages.

What I mean by "delete the feed of local data" is, for example:

- request is `page=0` of `friends_recents_photos`
- `onSuccess` -> `DELETE friends_recents_photos` -> `INSERT new data`
- then `onScroll` -> `loadMore`

  - request `page=1`
  - `onSuccess` -> `APPEND new data AT end`

but that's only the request data of that specific feed, other feeds (e.g. `followers`), detailed information (e.g. `UserData`) or cached/downloaded images is kept in cache for fast access.

Comment: So each time the user opens the app, the cached data is wiped? Would you also delete cached data when the user pulls on the UI to refresh?

Comment: Yes, wipe it, but ONLY for that one feed that the user request the new data. And no,  the `onPullToRefresh` is when you start the request, but you should only delete the cached when the request succeeds because: 1) you don't want a blank screen while the request is going to the server and back; 2) the request might fail, so old data is better than no data; 3) the user might want to interact more with the app while the request is going.

Comment: Feels a bit overkill but also a simple solution.

Comment: I understand your feeling, but read again your description and check from your own question how complex would be the target each individual item in a feed. Also, I suggest you to check out twitter clients, tumblr, you'll see that's pretty much what they all do.

Comment: I guess the trick there is to properly choose what to delete (only that one feed). Another example, it's a friends feed and there's a friend photo there, you'll only delete the photo itself, but not the friend profile data. So if the user clicks on that photo to navigate to the friend profile, that data is still cached. Makes sense ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that depending on the use case you just know if you need to delete the data or not. Do you have links to any of those apps so I can check their source code?

Comment: Personally I don't know none that are open source, but google for: "open source twitter client" you should find a view.